# CSS Tooltip box hidden

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a CSS tooltip box, and it is behind partially hidden within my content. 
I would like it that it would either extend past the content box, or move so it stay within the content box.

You can see the tooltip here http://aorasieconsultant.com/site.html on the second page when you hover over the images.

Link to page css file  http://aorasieconsultant.com/styles.css

Here is the tooltip css:

```
    a.tooltip{
    outline: none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: inherit;
    position:relative;
}
a.tooltip span{
    height: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:10px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    background:#B40406;  
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:0.8em;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
a.tooltip span:before,
a.tooltip span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:-11px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
a.tooltip span:after{
    bottom: -14px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    opacity: 0.95;
    bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant markup here instead of an external link? or perhaps create a jsfiddle that we can look at?

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle.  Have you tried specifying `clip: auto` in the `a.tooltip span` block?

Comment: I am just coming to say: nice site

Comment: If I create a jsfiddle I would have to recreate the whole site to really demonstrate my problem, the problem could be somewhere else in the css and I am not aware... 
`clip:auto` did not work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `customScrollBox` is the element that is covering the `tooltip`. Add `overflow:visible` to the `customScrollBox` and the `tooltip` extends beyond the bounds of the `customScrollBox`.

Comment: That worked, the tooltip can now leave the div, but now my scrolling text is not working. (scrolling vertically the text should remain in the div) I tried using `overflow-x:visible` and `overflow-y:hidden` but it gives me a horizontal scrollbar...